# Visualize matrix with colormap in grid

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, imshow

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
0.06    -0.22   -0.10   0.68    NaN     -0.33
0.04    -0.07   0.12    0.23    NaN     -0.47
NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     0.28
0.37    0.36    0.14    0.58    -0.14   -0.15
NaN     0.11    0.24    0.71    -0.13   NaN
0.57    0.53    0.41    0.65    -0.43   0.03
```

I want to color in each value based on a colormap. In Python, I know I can use `imshow` to assign a color to each box. How can I do it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use  [**`imshow`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imshow.html) as well, but every pixel would have the size of a pixel of your screen. So you may rather use [**`imagesc`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html).

```
A =  [...
0.06    -0.22   -0.10   0.68    NaN     -0.33;
0.04    -0.07   0.12    0.23    NaN     -0.47;
NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     0.28;
0.37    0.36    0.14    0.58    -0.14   -0.15;
NaN     0.11    0.24    0.71    -0.13   NaN;
0.57    0.53    0.41    0.65    -0.43   0.03 ]

imagesc(A)
```

And then you can apply any [**colormap**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) you want or [**create your own one**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormapeditor.html).

```
colormap(jet)
colorbar
```

[image]

---

If you don't like how `imagesc` handles your `NaN`s consider using [**`pcolor`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html)

```
pcolor(A)
colormap(jet)
colorbar
```

[image]

with `shading flat` you can get rid of the grid lines.