# How to do definitely associate colors to values in a heatmap in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, heatmap

I have a matrix M of integers (1, 2 or 3). I'd like to represent it with a heatmap and associate a fixed color to 1, 2 and 3. I use this piece of code :

```
map = [1, 1, 0;  % color for 1 (yellow)
       1, 0.5, 0 ; % color for 2 (orange)
       0, 1, 0.5]; % color for 3 (green)

HeatMap(M,'Colormap',map,'Symmetric','false');
```

When M contains at least one 1, one 2 and one 3, there isn't any problem. But when M contains only 3s for example, the heatmap isn't as I want (all green).
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need a heatmap? A similar result can be obtained by using other functions, such as `imshow`

Comment: I didn't know this function, thank you. I am trying to use it, but for now I have no satisfying results...

Comment: [Kovesi](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/) made some nice perceptually uniform colormaps as well. Might be helpful for you.

Comment: @Maurits Very interesting! I think in the newer versions of Matlab those problems are kind of solved,with e.g. the parula colormap.

Comment: you finally unaccepted both answers - why?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you can do this easily.
In Matlab 2013b or older (I haven't tried in 2014b) when you call `HeatMap` it internally goes through a process of creating axes and settin the colors and so on. Eventually it gets to a point inside `plot.m` where the following function is called:

```
function scaleHeatMap(hHMAxes, obj)
%SCALEHEATMAP Update the CLIM in image axes
if obj.Symmetric
    maxval = min(max(abs(obj.Data(:))), obj.DisplayRange);
    minval = -maxval;
else
    maxval = min(max(obj.Data(:)), obj.DisplayRange);
    minval = min(obj.Data(:));
end
set(hHMAxes, 'Clim', [minval,maxval]);
end
```

This function does actually define the limits of the colormap using the axes of the heatmap (`hHMAxes`), but that object is not returned by the `HeatMap()` call, unfortunately.

The only ways I can think of getting out of this problem are:

1. Modify the `plot.m` function. This is generally a quite bad idea.
2. Create a `myHeatMap` function, that does everything the original one does but with a changed functionality on the `Clim` property on the axes.
3. Do not use `HeatMap` at all and create an equally looking plot using e.g. `surf` or `imshow`.
4. Do an `if` statement before the call of `HeatMap`, and check if there is a single value in the colormap (`numel(unique(M(:)))==1`), and if that happens, change your `map` to a single valued colormap, with the color of your choice.

The easiest one is by far 4.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very precise response :)

Comment: @JuliaR No worries! Remeber to accept the answer if it was useful!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be not to use [**`HeatMap`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/heatmap.html) which is a quite inconvenient function based on Java.

[**Rather use**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152793/visualize-matrix-with-colormap-in-grid/29152877#29152877) [**`imagesc`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) or [**`pcolor`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) where you can easily fix the color axis with [**`caxis`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html):

```
map = [1, 1, 0;  % color for 1 (yellow)
       1, 0.5, 0 ; % color for 2 (orange)
       0, 1, 0.5]; % color for 3 (green)


%// left plot
subplot(131)
M = randi(3,3,3); 
imagesc(M)
colormap(map)
caxis( [1 3] )

%// right plot
subplot(132)
M = 3*ones(3); 
imagesc(M)
colormap(map)
caxis( [1 3] )

%// legend
subplot(133)
set(gca,'visible','off')
c = colorbar
caxis( [1 3] )
c.Ticks = [1.25,2,2.75]
c.TickLabels = 1:3
```

---

[image]

Comment: Great answer, indeed.